# Number of positive integers with precisely four mutually incongruent primitive roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would one determine this?  I can see that 11 and 13 each have 4 primitive roots.  There are two others apparently.  11 and 13 are prime but the problem is not restricted to mod p.  I know that if n has a primitive root, then n is 2, 4, a power of p, or double a power of p.  I believe that the remaining two integers are 22 and 26, which happen to be 2x11 and 2x13. I am not seeing why 22 has to have the same number of primitive roots as 11 (after all the primitive roots are not the same), for example.

Answer (score 1):

The group of units mod $n$ has order $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function, and if this is cyclic the number of primitive roots is $\phi(\phi(n))$.  We have
$$\eqalign{\phi(\phi(11)) &= \phi(10) = 4\cr
   \phi(\phi(13)) &= \phi(12) = 4\cr
   \phi(\phi(22)) &= \phi(10) = 4\cr
   \phi(\phi(26)) &= \phi(12) = 4\cr}$$
so all these cases have $4$ primitive roots.

You might start by determining which $m$ have $\phi(m)=4$.  Then which of those can be $\phi(p^k)$ or $\phi(2 p^k)$ for odd prime $p$.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.  I see how this helps find them.  I see how we can find 11, 13, 22, 26 using your help above.  How do I know there is not another number larger than 26 which also works?  I have not yet taken abstract algebra.

Comment: I think this would be because applying Euler's totient function twice to n where n is p^k or 2p^k (and where n is larger than 26) yields numbers greater than 4.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is an odd prime number, then the Chinese remainder theorem gives a ring isomorphism
$$\Bbb{Z}/2p\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\times(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}):\ k+2p\Bbb{Z}\ \longmapsto\ (k+2\Bbb{Z},k+p\Bbb{Z}).$$
This in turn yields a group isomorphism between the groups of units
$$(\Bbb{Z}/2p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\times(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}.$$
Of course $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is trivial and so we get an isomorphism
$$(\Bbb{Z}/2p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ (\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}:\ k+2p\Bbb{Z}\ \longmapsto\ k+p\Bbb{Z},$$
with inverse given by
$$(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\ \longrightarrow(\Bbb{Z}/2p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}:\ k+p\Bbb{Z}\ \longmapsto\ \begin{cases}k+2p\Bbb{Z}&\text{ if $k$ is odd}\\k+p+2p\Bbb{Z}&\text{ if $k$ is even}\end{cases}$$
Because these two groups are isomorphic, their numbers of generators (primitive roots) are equal.